# One user has a bug while other users don't have that bug

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog

So, I'm working on an app with the platform Xamarin. However, one user has a annoying bug that won't go away. What's weirder, is that this user is the only user with this bug. I could not reproduce this with emulators and physical devices and another user does not have this bug as well. The client uses a Samsung Galaxy A5(2016) (a5xelte). After searching the crash reports, I discovered that the client has this crash report:

```
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: at ACD.App.Droid.Alert+AlertDialogFragment+<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<HappyAlert>b__0 (System.Object <sender>, System.EventArgs <e>) [0x0001d] in <c345aa7ad2f34bfc8b384470d2386f05>:0
at Android.Views.View+IOnClickListenerImplementor.OnClick (Android.Views.View v) [0x00011] in <e3db7c3b36704d7ea2a7892711a8a46d>:0
at Android.Views.View+IOnClickListenerInvoker.n_OnClick_Landroid_view_View_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_v) [0x0000f] in <e3db7c3b36704d7ea2a7892711a8a46d>:0
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:209af83e-6acd-4fa8-ae0f-b79f18f9b39f (intptr,intptr,intptr)
at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick (Native Method)
at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick (View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30)
at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6261)
at android.widget.TextView.performClick (TextView.java:11159)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:23748)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1496)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

My question is, why does this user has this bug while other users don't have that bug? And how can I prevent something like this in the future?

Here are the images from the devices:

Image on user's device
[image]
Image on other devices:
[image]

And finally, here's the code where the error takes place:

```
public void HappyAlert(Android.Views.LayoutInflater inflater, AlertDialog.Builder builder)
        {

            Android.Views.View secondView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.HappySliderLayout, null);
            builder.SetView(secondView);

            TextView title = secondView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Login);
            title.Text = Title;

            TextView body = secondView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.pincodeText);
            body.Text = Body;
            body.MovementMethod = new Android.Text.Method.ScrollingMovementMethod();

            Android.Widget.Button btnNeutral = secondView.FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.btnNeutral);
            ImageView imgHappy = secondView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgHappy);
            ImageView imgSad = secondView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgSad);


            var happySlider = secondView.FindViewById<SeekBar>(Resource.Id.happinessSlider);

            happySlider.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;
            btnNeutral.Text = Buttons.First().Text;
            btnNeutral.Click += delegate
            {
                var car = (StackLayout)Content;

                var layoutView = (Xamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout)car.Children[1];
                var slider = (Slider)layoutView.Children[1];

                var totalHappyValue = happySlider.Progress / 10;
                slider.Value = totalHappyValue;


                CommandsForButtons(Buttons.First());
            };
        }
```

Comment: Did you check the Android version installed on each device?

Comment: Yes I did. I tested it with different Android versions on my emulators and physical devices and the user has a android 7.0 version

Comment: Dis you check also the configuration of the phone concerning the accessibility (font size, etc.) ?

Comment: I created an emulator which has identical specifications of the user´s cellphone. I did not found any font issues and besides, I used dp in my layouts to make sure that the screen stays the same on every device.

Comment: You should try with px (I know that's not the solution but it will help to find if these parameters make a difference)

Comment: Is this issue only happens on Android 7.0? Looks like a bug of Android 7.0, I saw someone said that defining a custom theme for `AlertDialog` may solve this issue.

Comment: The issue indeed only happens on Android 7.0. What´s interesting is that more users with Android 7.0 have the crash report, but not the visual bug. Is there a way to get more information from the crash report on Google Play Console? I want to know why the happy alerts keeps crashing even though I haven't encountered that bug(used emulators and physical devices).